# Deploying Java Application As Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a java application that up until now was run as a stand alone java application (i.e. executable jar). I now need to deploy it in Tomcat as a servlet. It doesn't need to actually process any HTTP requests though, but it needs to be started using tomcat.

What are the steps required to convert the project so that it can be deployed in Tomcat? I'm using maven as a build tool and Java 1.5.

Comment: What is the application going to do if it doesn't process any HTTP requests? Why not just daemonize it if it's not handling requests?

Comment: This question is so general it can't easily be answered. Is your application organized in an MVC fashion?

Comment: @Kaleb - It is currently deamonized. But it now needs to share a connection with another application running in tomcat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand that you want to run this app on server's startup. The best way would be implementing [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and run the app in the `contextInitialized()` method. E.g.

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    private YourApp yourApp;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        yourApp = new YourApp();
        yourApp.start();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        yourApp.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Register this in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.example.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

That's it. No need to wrap it in flavor of a `HttpServlet` as you aren't going to fire HTTP requests on it.

You however need to ensure that it runs in its own thread, otherwise it would block the startup. If it doesn't, then wrap it in a [`Runnable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) and execute it using [`ExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your app is continuously running and you have an app/web server already (e.g. Tomcat/Jetty), such that it's making your life easy to deploy into it. Given that, you need to:

1. extend an `AbstractHttpServlet` class and in particular the init() method. This would start your app.
2. build a `web.xml` that references this and sets the load-on-startup attribute to 1 (or at least non-zero)
3. build a .war from this and deploy it

Step 2 ensures that the `init()` method is called upon deployment/server reboot, and so you don't have to respond to HTTP requests (a normal startup trigger for a servlet).

It may be simpler and more appropriate to use something like [javaservicewrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org/doc/english/download.jsp), and wrap it up to be a Windows service or similar.

Comment: +1: basically, AbstractHttpServlet.init() is just another entry point, ala public static main(String[] args) for a regular cmd line started app.